# Laravel carbon not catching exception

Tags: php, laravel, exception, php-carbon

i have a simple class:

```
public function CreateCustomer()
{
 .
 .
 try{
      $birthDate = Carbon::parse($birth)->toIso8601String();
    }catch (\Exception $ex){
      die("error");
    }
```

And on top of the controller:

```
use Exception;
```

I get an error that the exception was Not caught

```
InvalidArgumentException
Unexpected data found. Trailing data
```

i've even tried to catch "InvalidArgumentException", but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, it was on

```
 ->toIso8601String();
```

As it was generating a double, uncaught exception